# Flutter Stackoverflow Error when using Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stack-overflow

I don't know where this Stackoverflow Error comes from

```
I/flutter (20342): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    I/flutter (20342): The following StackOverflowError was thrown building Analytics(dirty):
    I/flutter (20342): Stack Overflow
    I/flutter (20342):
    I/flutter (20342): The relevant error-causing widget was:
    I/flutter (20342):   Analytics
    I/flutter (20342):   file:///C:/Users/OneDrive/Dokumente/Development/GitHub/trimlog/src/flutter_app/lib/screens/wrapper.dart:87:11
    I/flutter (20342):
    I/flutter (20342): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    I/flutter (20342): #0      _LinkedHashMapMixin._getValueOrData (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:331:3)
    I/flutter (20342): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.containsKey (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:355:54)
    I/flutter (20342): #2      FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor (package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:50:26)
    I/flutter (20342): #3      new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart:39:97)
    I/flutter (20342): #4      new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #5      new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #6      new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #7      new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #8      new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #9      new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #10     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #11     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #12     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #13     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #14     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #15     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #16     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #17     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #18     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #19     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #20     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #21     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #22     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #23     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #24     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #25     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #26     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #27     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #28     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #29     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #30     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #31     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #32     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #33     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #34     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #35     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #36     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #37     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #38     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #39     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #40     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #41     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #42     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): #43     new Database (package:Trimlog/services/database/database.dart)
    I/flutter (20342): ...
    I/flutter (20342): ...
    I/flutter (20342): #15600  ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
    I/flutter (20342): #15601  StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
    I/flutter (20342): #15602  ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
    I/flutter (20342): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
    I/flutter (20342): #15609  Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
    I/flutter (20342): #15610  Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
    I/flutter (20342): #15611  SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1158:36)
    I/flutter (20342): #15612  SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1143:20)    
    I/flutter (20342): #15613  BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2683:19)
    I/flutter (20342): #15614  SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1136:11)
    I/flutter (20342): #15615  RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:350:23)
    I/flutter (20342): #15616  RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1883:59)
    I/flutter (20342): #15617  PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:915:15)
    I/flutter (20342): #15618  RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1883:14)
    I/flutter (20342): #15619  RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:339:5)
    I/flutter (20342): #15620  RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:485:5)
    I/flutter (20342): #15621  RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:259:17)
    I/flutter (20342): #15622  RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
    I/flutter (20342): #15623  RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:132:12)
    I/flutter (20342): #15624  _RenderSliverFractionalPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver_fill.dart:170:11)
    I/flutter (20342): #15625  RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
    I/flutter (20342): #15626  RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:507:13)
    I/flutter (20342): #15627  RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1561:12)
    I/flutter (20342): #15628  RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1470:20)
    I/flutter (20342): #15629  RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
    I/flutter (20342): #15630  PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:884:18)
    I/flutter (20342): #15631  RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:436:19)
    I/flutter (20342): #15632  WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:914:13)
    I/flutter (20342): #15633  RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:302:5)
    I/flutter (20342): #15634  SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
    I/flutter (20342): #15635  SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:9)
    I/flutter (20342): #15636  SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:971:5)
    I/flutter (20342): #15640  _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:251:10)
    I/flutter (20342): #15641  _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:3)
    I/flutter (20342): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
    I/flutter (20342):
    I/flutter (20342): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    I/flutter (20342): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'analytic' was called on null.
```

In my main.dart

```
class Instances {
  static Database database = new Database();
}
```

In database.dart

```
class Database {
  final _databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance; // Instance of Firebase
  final user = new DatabaseUser();
  final boat = new DatabaseBoat();
  final trim = new DatabaseTrim();
  final analytic = new DatabaseAnalytic();
```

In database_analytic.dart

```
class DatabaseAnalytic extends Database {
```

How I access for example DatabaseAnalytic

```
Instances.database.analytic.deleteAnalyticOfBoat(widget.boat.documentid, widget.analytic.documentid)
```

wrapper.dart: https://hastebin.com/eholocelug.java

Can someone tell me where the error comes from?

I have seen, that it says "The getter 'analytic' was called on null.", but I cannot figure out why that is.

I am also not sure whether this is the best way to work with the Database, if there is a better way it would be great if you let me know.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: The instance of analytic is returning null

Comment: I have seen that, but why is the question...

Comment: Can you pls post your `lib/screens/wrapper.dart` code ?

Comment: Here is my whole wrapper.dart https://hastebin.com/eholocelug.java

Comment: @PlutoHDDev on the line 87 of your `wrapper.dart` file I can see you make instantiation of the `Analytics()` class. Can you do the same by posting it's code ?

Comment: So you also want the code of Analytics()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the rest of the error, Database is constantly being instantiated over and over again.   Database is instantiating DatabaseAnalytic which is instantiating Database again.  It's what is causing an overflow error.

Answer (score 1):

We can see this in your error output

> Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'analytic' was called on null.

With this line

```
Instances.database.analytic.deleteAnalyticOfBoat(widget.boat.documentid,widget.analytic.documentid)
```

Your error assumes that `Instances.database` is `null`

Comment: So where do you think the bug really is? I don't quite understand where you think the problem is.